# Calling OnResume upon Getting Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to have my notification builder call only `OnResume()` upon the Intent being fired, similar to when the user chooses the app from background running apps.  I've tried numerous flags, but I am not getting the result I desire.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction("OPEN_TAB_CONTACTS");         
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.antartica7);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert, Click Me!");
mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, This is Android Notification Detail,WEWWW!");
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);


NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify("newmessage", 1, mBuilder.build());
```

---

I have tried adding

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

and

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

to the AndroidManifest as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since no flags were working, I instead check what the Intent action is manually.

Added this to `onCreate()`:

```
if(getIntent().getAction() != null) {

    if(getIntent().getAction().equals("OPEN_TAB_CONTACTS")) {
        System.out.println("Pending intent called");
    } else {
        //normal onCreate
    }
}
```